# Click events passing though SVG element (no bounding box)

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG (target) element that contains a couple SVG (decedents) elements, this container SVG is deep inside the SVG (root) that sits in the page. The problem I'm seeing is that if I register an event on the SVG (target) the event only fires if you click on one of the SVG (decedents) as if there is no bounding box for the SVG (target). Other than filling the SVG (target) with a transparent rect of 100% x 100% what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

why not assign event using some different kind of approach. Assigning attribute to Elements. for example:-

Let say below is your svg:-

```
<svg ... >

 <g id='container' data-action='selection'>
 <g id='child1' data-action='selection'>
</g>

 <g id='child2' data-action='selection'>
</g>


</g>

</svg>
```

Now in code, bind event on document.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown',useraction,false);

function useraction(event){

if(event.target.hasAttribute('data-action')){
  var action=event.target.getAttribute('data-action');

   if(action==='selection'){
   //call your selection function to perform action.
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: The issue was that the g elements were transparent even if I bound on a higher level element.

Comment: it would be nice if you upload a fiddle (an example) or pictorial explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also its an issue with jQuery not supporting SVG but ill post a jsBin soon.